# Sprites change correctly in the build on a creator computer but not on any other devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, sprite

Building the application creates a fully working .exe or .app that when run perfectly has all of the functionalities and, most importantly, changes the sprites correctly. The sprite change mentioned is when the user moves in different directions and the script changes the sprite on the player GameObject accordingly. Everything works as it is supposed to in the editor and in the local build (.exe).

The problem is though that when the build folder (incl. .exe) is sent to any other computer the sprites stop changing. Only the main sprite that was used to render the GameObject in the first place is shown.

I have tried to switch from single file sprites to a sprite map instead but that has not fixed the issue either.

The strangest thing is that everything works as it is supposed to in every build on the local machine and in the editor but never on any other devices (PC/Windows, Mac/Mac OS X).

PS! I have thought whether it is the issue that the sprite files are not included in the final build but adding all the sprites on a single sprite map should have fixed the issue. Also, everything works on the local computer.

PlayerControls.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerControls : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Sprite westView;
    public Sprite eastView;
    public Sprite northView;
    public Sprite southView;

    public GameObject player;

    public float speed = 5f;

    private Tilemap tilemap;

    void Start()
    {
        tilemap = GameObject.Find("Grid/Walls").GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        player.GetComponent<EntityMove>().setSpeed(speed);
        player.GetComponent<EntityMove>().setTiles(tilemap);
        player.GetComponent<ControlSprite>().setSprites(new Sprite[] { northView, westView, eastView, southView});
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!isLocalPlayer)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) { changeSprite(0); }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { changeSprite(1); }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) { changeSprite(2); }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) { changeSprite(3); }
        player.GetComponent<EntityMove>().setTiles(tilemap);
    }

    [Client]
    private void changeSprite(int newDirection)
    {
        if (newDirection == 0) { gameObject.GetComponent<ControlSprite>().newSprite(player, northView, 0); }
        else if (newDirection == 1) { gameObject.GetComponent<ControlSprite>().newSprite(player, westView, 1); }
        else if (newDirection == 2) { gameObject.GetComponent<ControlSprite>().newSprite(player, eastView, 2); }
        else if (newDirection == 3) { gameObject.GetComponent<ControlSprite>().newSprite(player, southView, 3); }
    }
}
```

PS! The public sprites are linked to the prefab assets and sprites.

ControlSprite.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ControlSprite : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Sprite[] possibleSprites;

    [Command]
    void CmdProvideSpriteChangeToServer(GameObject entity, int newDirection)
    {
        entity.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = possibleSprites[newDirection];

        RpcSendSpriteChange(entity, newDirection);
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcSendSpriteChange(GameObject entity, int newDirection)
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer) return;

        entity.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = possibleSprites[newDirection];
    }

    public void newSprite(GameObject entity, Sprite newSprite, int newDirection)
    {
        entity.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = newSprite;
        CmdProvideSpriteChangeToServer(entity, newDirection);
    }

    public void setSprites(Sprite[] newSprites) { possibleSprites = newSprites; }
}
```

[image: Player Prefab]

Comment: Could you show the code of changing the sprites? Do you maybe get them from a certain folder/download them etc ?

Comment: Added code but I don't see how this could be the problem as the .exe works as it is supposed to on the creators computer. Also, I'm not taking any sprites from folder specific places and only using prefabs.

Comment: Ofcourse it matters .. now we see you are using some networking so the first question: Are you methods over the network called at all?

Comment: Yes. The localhost works on the client computer and every other client on the same computer. When sprite changing stops working is when the same .exe and all of the accompaning files in the build folder are distributed. In short, everything works as it is supposed to. To test this locally I just use multiple clients and simulate LAN.

Comment: sounds like a networking problem then ...

Comment: But how if the spirtes stop working on the local machine also when distributed? They should not be affected by the server/client relations anyway. As can be seen from the ControlSprite.cs - the sprite is changed locally without ever even having to talk to the server. The problem is that even this change does not happen on the client side.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using? This GUI looks like one of the 2019.3a alpha versions. Alpha versions are **only** for testing newes features but are not stable for development and full of bugs/known issues. Maybe yu shuld stick to the latest stable version 2019.1.7 and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the 2019.3.0a5 version, might try the stable one to see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the people who tried to play the game used arrow keys instead of WASD to move but the script only changes direction of the sprite when the WASD keys are pressed.